# Android, AsyncTask not running on onDestroy()

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask

I am facing a problem that when I close my application, I want to stop a service and run a method

> new sendLogoutDetail().execute(AccountID);

to update my database. I put the methods in onDestroy() but when i end my application, the Log Cat is filled with lots of error and my method doesn't run at all.

Here is my Android code:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    String AccountID = null;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null){
        AccountID = extras.getString("AccountID");
    }
    new sendLogoutDetail().execute(AccountID);
    stopService(new Intent(this,getLocationService.class));
}

private class sendLogoutDetail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(LoggedIn.this, "Ending Service","Loading..", true);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI + "/DeleteLoginPool");
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");            
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        JSONStringer getWifiInfo;
        try {
            getWifiInfo = new JSONStringer()
                .object()
                    .key("staffLocate")
                        .object()                               
                            .key("AccountID").value(params[0])
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject();

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getWifiInfo.toString());

        request.setEntity(entity);

        // Send request to WCF service
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And my log cat:

```
>06-19 18:42:09.626: W/asset(22278): deep redirect failure from 0x01030117 => 0x0a0a0004, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x0103008f, style=0x010302eb
>06-19 18:42:09.626: W/asset(22278): deep redirect failure from 0x01030117 => 0x0a0a0004, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x0103008f, style=0x010302eb
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278): Activity com.example.staffallocatorproject.LoggedIn has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{413f5790 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0} that was originally added here
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.staffallocatorproject.LoggedIn has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{413f5790 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0} that was originally added here
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at com.example.staffallocatorproject.LoggedIn$sendLogoutDetail.onPreExecute(LoggedIn.java:57)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at com.example.staffallocatorproject.LoggedIn.onDestroy(LoggedIn.java:45)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5391)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3568)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3599)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:156)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
>06-19 18:42:09.688: E/WindowManager(22278):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>06-19 18:42:09.719: E/<<myServiceRunner-onDestroy>>(22278): I am dead-3
```

Comment: why u put the methos on onDestrory can u elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are showing a `ProgressDialog` when your `Activity` is getting destroyed. So if you want to do some background operation when your Activity gets destroyed just don't show the `ProgressDialog`. So, in that case `AsyncTask` with only `doInBackground()` should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can't show any dialog when the activity is destroyed.

what you can do is override onBackPressed (and any place you call finish() ) , and there you show what you need, and when it finishes whatever you wish for it to do, finish the activity.